# PuTTY 'use font encoding' meaning

Tags: fonts, putty, encoding

Could someone tell me what 'Use font encoding' exactly means? I haven't been able to find any documentation about it.

((
Just FYI

Actually my problem is:

Terminal: Putty // Remote Character Set // UTF-8

Server: Debian // bash // LANG=es_ES.UTF-8

All works fine, even

```
vim file_with_accents
```

But

```
cat file_with_accents
```

shows garbled characters.

But if I configure PuTTY changing in "Remote Character Set", "UTF-8" to "Use Font Encoding", cat works fine while vim displays accented characters wrong.

))

Comment: Does the _file_ contain UTF-8 encoded text? Setting $LANG will not make `cat` re-encode files, it only affects programs' own output.

Answer (score 1):

### Encodings and Character sets

As I expect you know, before Unicode and UTF8 became widespread, there were many different encodings such as CP850 and CP437. For example code point 188 is ╝ in CP437, but is ¼ in Unicode.

### PuTTY

If you communicate with a server application that emits characters in say CP437, Putty needs to know that so that it can perform the correct translation into a common encoding that it can use to select appropriate glyphs from available fonts. PuTTY has to be configured to turn 188 into ╝ instead of ¼. Normally I would do this by explicitly setting the "remote character set" to "CP437".

Every font also has an implicit encoding. I guess, by selecting "use font encoding" rather than setting an explicit value, you are telling Putty to use the inherent mappings in the font to find the glyph to use for any received byte values.

You can explore this a bit, set "Remote Character Set" to `Use Font Encoding`. Set "Font used in the terminal Window" to, say, `Lucida Console` and in that dialog change "script" from `Western` to `Greek` and notice the effect this has in both the "Sample" in the dialog and in your cat output after the settings have been applied. The available values for "Script" depend on the font selected. Personally I would set the encoding explicitly, but perhaps there are niche use-cases where it is necessary to use an encoding determined by a special font.

### Vim

The editor `vim` can detect some encodings in files and will translate from a file encoding (`fenc`) into a display encoding (`enc`) set by environment variables (LOCALE, LANG etc). In vim you can view these settings using `:set fenc` and `:set enc`.

### Cat

In my experience, `cat` does not perform any translations between file encoding and display encoding.

### Outcomes

This may be why you get different results using vim and cat, vim is converting the file's text into an encoding that matches what PuTTY expects (either explicitly or which matches the encoding implicit in the selected font and script).

Comment: Thanks RedGrittyBrick!  This is the key: "Every font also has an implicit encoding. I guess, by selecting "use font encoding" rather than setting an explicit value, you are telling Putty to use the inherent mappings in the font to find the glyph to use for any received byte values."

Answer (score 1):

When I set the character set to Use font encoding, I was getting alpha characters instead of lines when I brought up nmon, but normal lines when I used the pstree command with -p, but the opposite when I selected UTF-8.

I resolved this by selecting UTF-8 as the Remote character set, and then, under Handling of line drawing characters, selecting Use font in both ANSI and OEM modes, and also checking the box next to Enable VT100 line drawing even in UTF-8 mode.

Now, every command, every screen, and every file appears with the correct characters and lines.